# Azure DocumentDB: The read session is not available for the input session token

Tags: c#, azure, caching, azure-web-app-service, azure-cosmosdb

So I have this intermittent exception being thrown. After research I made sure my `DocumentClient` object was cached and used throughout the app lifetime and I have updated all my Nuget packages to the latest version. Using Visual Studio 2015 on a local debugging session.

I am working on a `Document` memory caching mechanism. At some point I want to insert an object into the cache and retrieve the resultant `Document` object. So first I add the object to the DocumentDB. Here is what I do:

```
await docClient.CreateDocumentAsync(uriCollection, docInit).ConfigureAwait(false);
docCacheEntry = await DirectQueryForDocument(docClient, uriCollection, strDocId).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

The reason for this is because I want the `Document` properties initialized (like `ETag`, for example).

But (sometimes) when I call `DirectQueryForDocument()`, it throws this:

```
DocDBTrace Error: 0 : DocumentClientException with status code: NotFound, message: The read session is not available for the input session token.
ActivityId: 458a5727-98a5-4fef-999a-1fddb68e5cdc, 
ResponseTime: 2017-11-04T17:31:23.7938911Z <truncated>
ResponseTime: 2017-11-04T17:31:23.7938911Z <truncated>
ResponseTime: 2017-11-04T17:31:23.7938911Z <truncated>
ResponseTime: 2017-11-04T17:31:23.8138911Z <truncated>
, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/1.17.91.3, and response headers: {
"Transfer-Encoding": "chunked",
"x-ms-substatus": "1002",
"x-ms-activity-id": "458a5727-98a5-4fef-999a-1fddb68e5cdc",
"Strict-Transport-Security": "max-age=31536000",
"x-ms-gatewayversion": "version=1.17.91.3",
"Date": "Sat, 04 Nov 2017 17:31:23 GMT",
"Server": "Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0",
}
DocDBTrace Warning: 0 : Read session not available. Retry using write endpoint.
DocDBTrace Error: 0 : DocumentClientException with status code: NotFound, message: The read session is not available for the input session token.
ActivityId: 9133c4cb-e1eb-4f21-86d3-3301c1e194f8, 
ResponseTime: 2017-11-04T17:31:24.3539231Z <truncated>
ResponseTime: 2017-11-04T17:31:24.3539231Z <truncated>
ResponseTime: 2017-11-04T17:31:24.3539231Z <truncated>
ResponseTime: 2017-11-04T17:31:24.3539231Z <truncated>
, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/1.17.91.3, and response headers: {
"Transfer-Encoding": "chunked",
"x-ms-substatus": "1002",
"x-ms-activity-id": "9133c4cb-e1eb-4f21-86d3-3301c1e194f8",
"Strict-Transport-Security": "max-age=31536000",
"x-ms-gatewayversion": "version=1.17.91.3",
"Date": "Sat, 04 Nov 2017 17:31:23 GMT",
"Server": "Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0",
}
DocDBTrace Warning: 0 : Clear the the token for named base request dbs/lps/colls/cache-tables
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.Azure.Documents.DocumentClientException' in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: The read session is not available for the input session token.
ActivityId: 9133c4cb-e1eb-4f21-86d3-3301c1e194f8, 
ResponseTime: 2017-11-04T17:31:24.3539231Z <truncated>
ResponseTime: 2017-11-04T17:31:24.3539231Z <truncated>
ResponseTime: 2017-11-04T17:31:24.3539231Z <truncated>
ResponseTime: 2017-11-04T17:31:24.3539231Z <truncated>
, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/1.17.91.3
```

Here is the source for `DirectQueryForDocument()` (where the exception is thrown)

```
private static async Task<Document> DirectQueryForDocument(DocumentClient docClient, Uri uriCollection, string strId)
{
    var query = docClient.CreateDocumentQuery(uriCollection).Where((x) => x.Id == strId).AsDocumentQuery();
    if (query.HasMoreResults)
    {
        // exception is thrown on next line
        var res = await query.ExecuteNextAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        if (res.Count == 1)
        {
            return res.Single();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Obviously I could just catch the exception and just not add it to my memory-cache then try again down the line when the document is requested, but that defeats the entire purpose of having a cache.

What am I missing?

ETA:
I just realized I don't need to query to get the `Document` in the database, I can just do this to save a ton of time:

```
var resDoc = await docClient.CreateDocumentAsync(uriCollection, docInit).ConfigureAwait(false);
docCacheEntry = resDoc.Resource;
```

But, I'd still like to know why this is happening at all!

Comment: What consistency level is configured for the collection?

Comment: @PeterBons: well, since i have no idea what you are talking about, it would have to be the default level because I don't believe I ever set that :)